# While debugging this code fragment ,this error occurs

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-crawler, remote-server

While debugging this code fragment ,this error(Unable to connect remote server) occurs.I showed where error occured in comment line

```
private static string GetWebText(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        request.UserAgent = "A .NET Web Crawler";

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();//errors occured here

        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string htmlText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return htmlText;
    }
```

Comment: What is the error stack? If you are using it within the organisation, make sure you verify your proxy.

Comment: And if you go to the very same url using browser, what do you get ?

Comment: i just try to run my code but it says unable to connect remote server

Comment: Maybe it's about Web.Config: http://forums.asp.net/t/1585771.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should try to figuere out what is wrong, it can be wrong url or something that goes wrong with the request / response. In order to look at the traffic behind your application I would suggest using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) for checking what happens behind the scene.